# fancytikzposter damage pdf

Tags: tikz-pgf, posters

I am using fancytikzposter, but for some reason that I do not understand the pdf file generated cannot be opened from another computer, here is my code that I got from [here](http://www.inf.unibz.it/~ebotoeva/fancytikzposter.html).

```
\documentclass{a0poster}
\usepackage{fancytikzposter} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{epsfig,graphicx}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[margin=\margin cm, paperwidth=84.1cm, paperheight=122cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage[math]{kurier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\title{Percolation Theory}
\author{Tom}
\begin{document}
\ClearShipoutPicture
\AddToShipoutPicture{\BackgroundPicture}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}

...

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Also I add some images png and pdf, also change text.

The error showed it is: There was an error opening this document. The file is damage and could not be required.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: also I noticed that the file works fine in another mac, but on windows shows the message.

Comment: Which application can open it on the Macs? If it is a PDF, try opening Adobe Reader (or preferred viewer) on the Windows box and then open the file from the menu. Or check that Windows knows what kind of file it is. Does the file have the `.pdf` extension? Does the Windows machine have a PDF viewer? (I've seen lots of university machines which don't for some reason.)

Comment: adobe pdf does not work on windows. And it has .pdf extension.